# Set SpringJoint2D anchor point via script in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I'm trying to set the position of the connected anchor of a 2d spring joint via script. I'm using

```
SpringJoint2D springJoint = GetComponent<SpringJoint2d>();
springJoint.connectedAnchor.Set(somex, somey);
```

which isn't working. I can't imagine any other way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

A little late, but for the future:

Your code must include:

```
springJoint.connectedBody.WakeUp();
```

as this wakes up the rigidbody. The reason `Set()` did not work is because this was not called, and the rigidbody was still asleep.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, just used

```
springJoint.connectedAnchor = new Vector2(somex, somey);
```

Can't believe I didn't think of that, although I don't know why Set() doesn't work.